# Tuple of int values to string

Tags: python, type-conversion

I need to do a conversion like this in Python:

```
(1, 0, 7, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 5)
```

to

```
'107238465'
```

How can do that?

Comment: `reduce(lambda a, b: a + str(b), (1, 0, 7, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 5), "")`

Comment: Simpler: `"".join(map(str, (1, 0, 7, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 5)))`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way should be with a [list comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) or a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
t = (1, 2, 3, 4)    
''.join([str(a) for a in t])  # list comprehension
```

or

```
''.join(str(a) for a in t)  # generator expression
```

you need the list comprehension or generator expression to convert numbers to strings, if you had a tuple of strings you could get away with:

```
t = ('a', 'b', 'c')
''.join(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

This runs in 2/3 of the time of @georstef's answer on my computer

```
>>> str(reduce(lambda x, y: x * 10 + y, (1, 0, 7, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 5)))
'107238465'
```

A few other ways are compared below

```
timeit ''.join([str(a) for a in t])
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.94 us per loop

timeit ''.join(str(a) for a in t)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.39 us per loop

timeit str(reduce(lambda x, y: x * 10 + y, t))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.06 us per loop

timeit str(t)[1: -1].replace(", ", "")
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.8 us per loop

timeit str(t).translate(None, "(), ")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 us per loop
```